# Finding the Magnetic Field within a solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, inductance

So, I have to find the magnetic field within a solenoid such that the field at a point(on axis) is half than that it would be at the centre. Length of the solenoid is 20cm and the current through it is 10. Number of turns is 200.
(In the question the radius of solenoid is not given so I'm assuming it to be L>>>R so that it can be ignored in calculation as it would be minuscule)

So my idea is take that point to be x and then take integral of magnetic fields by each singular loop with appropriate limits. (I'm attaching photo as writing the integral as newbie is very hard for me).

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yAFDsINzZJfYaFDkmpco_js1tdEawJJw/view?usp=share_link

I have done it so far but on evaluating the integral I'm getting a wierd answer. Is there a flaw in my method?
Do ask anything in the comments you might not understand due to poor handwriting.

Comment: Please use MathJax for writing formulas. It is easy, even for newbies!

Comment: @Hyperon next time will do